# How to refresh sliderInput on parameterized rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Using this dummy parameterized Rmarkdown html document, how can I refresh the sliderInput control?
After dragging the slider both ways or one way, it stays that way for the next session. I would like to default to the value given in the yaml (value: [2010,2017] after every session.

````
    ---
title: "Animals"
output:
  html_document:
params:
  animal_name:
    value: Dog
    choices:
      - Dog
      - Cat
      - Rabbit
  years_of_study:
    input: slider
    min: 2000
    max: 2019
    step: 1
    round: 1
    sep: ''
    value: [2010, 2017]
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are only "memorized" by RStudio's internal browser. If you run `rmarkdown::render()` with `params = "ask"` the parameter input interface will open in your browser and always defaults to the values you defined in the YAML.

```
rmarkdown::render("animals.Rmd", params = "ask")
```